Recursive calls to make with $(MAKE) are ignoring my bash script
I have defined my own wrapper of make by using an script that includes a call to time in front of each invocation of make (updating the PATH so bash finds my make first, etc). The script looks like:
#!/bin/bash
time /usr/bin/make -w "$@"
echo "Finished: make $@"

However, when a call to make is done inside a Makefile by using $(MAKE), make is calling /usr/bin/make. For example:
target:
    $(MAKE) -C subfolder

When I do make target, my script is being used, but then, /usr/bin/make identifies the exact binary that is being called (itself), and use that exact binary to expand $(MAKE).
How can I get all calls to make or $(MAKE) use the script? Or in general, how can I force all invocations of make, whatever the way it's invoked (plain make or $(MAKE)) have a time in front of it and contains the option -w?
Note: without modifying the text of any of the existing makefiles.

You replace /usr/bin/make with your script. And break a ton of things along the way. Maybe do this in a container or VM to not draw the wrath of the other users?

@BobGoddard I said the word alias, but it was a wrapper script. I have fixed the question.

@Jens Won't do it. $(MAKE) will always find the "real" make wherever I invoke it. If I replace /usr/bin/make by a script that calls the real make in /random_place/bin/make, $(MAKE) will point to /random_place/bin/make.

The problem is that make runs whatever make you invoked.  Your script is not make.  Your script INVOKES make.  So, to make the name of the program invoking make is /usr/bin/make, because that's the program your script is invoking (your script says time /usr/bin/make ...).  There's no possible way that make can know the name of the script that contained a call to /usr/bin/make, unless you tell it explicitly.  You will have to set a variable, like time /usr/bin/make MAKE=<myscript> ...

The MAKE= override seems to work fine. I thought make would define that later or something (like MAKE would be a special variable that is overriden just at the beginning of each makefile(, but it looks like it's inherit just fine in recursive calls throughout MAKEFLAGS.

make itself knows nothing about how it was launched except its own name and arguments as specified in the command that launched it (inside your script, in this case, not the script itself).  It does not know that it was launched via a wrapper script, much less which wrapper script.

The answer is kind of simple: Do not use $(MAKE), use your own script instead.
As documentation stated:

MAKE
The name with which make was invoked. Using this variable in recipes has special meaning. See How the MAKE Variable Works.

In the "How the MAKE variable works" you can see

The value of this variable is the file name with which make was invoked. ... If you use a special version of make to run the top-level makefile, the same special version will be executed for recursive invocations.

The disadvantage of using your own script for sub-makes is that you will lose ability to work with automatically exported variables and parameters, unless you export them into environment or as manual parameters for sub-make. But if you do not use them, you can easily done something like:
target:
    cd subfolder && mymake 

Read here about recursive use of make:
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recursion

The solution is as simple as:
#!/bin/bash
time /usr/bin/make -w "$@" MAKE=make
echo "Finished: make $@"

I had a couple of misunderstandings before. First, I thought that make somehow "calculated" the absolute path of the executable. No, it takes the literal string that you wrote in the command line. Basically the $0 in bash jargon. I was observing the string /usr/bin/make because that's what's literally written in the wrapper script.
Second, I thought the MAKE variable also contained the flags specified. My confusion I think comes from the fact that the presence of MAKE causes make to give an special treatment of some of the flags specified on the command line. That documented association MAKE variable versus command line arguments made me believe that MAKE contained somehow the flags. That's false, the flags specified is stored in an environmental variable called MAKEFLAGS.
Third, I thought that the MAKE variable was set at the beginning of the parse, and I didn't think that specifying MAKE on the command line like in the wrapper above will work at all, I assumed that it would be overriden as soon as make starts executing. That's false as well.
Another misconception was that the flags specified were lost if you call make recursively using make instead of $(MAKE). False. It's inherited in both cases.
In total, when I specify MAKE=make, my value is taken instead of what I wrote on the command line, and MAKEFLAGS will contain something like MAKEFLAGS=w -- MAKE=make, so my setting is preserved across recursive calls both using plan make and $(MAKE), which means that MAKE is make at all moments, so enabling the use of my wrapper in all situations.
